# stop asking for download an embedded file on unavailability of plugin to display

Tags: html, embed

I'd embedded a `pdf` file on my page. On some `browsers` it shows properly that `pdf` file but on some browser instead of showing that file it ask me to download that file.
One of the possible reason could be unavailability of plugin in the browser to display the file.
But I want that if it was unable to show do not ask the file to download.

[URL for reference](http://mypragati.org/html/registration.php)

Comment: That is usually up to the browser implementation.  If you're trying to send a PDF to display, usually a PDF reader (installed on the browser) will intercept that download request.

Comment: @BLaZuRE: true. But how could I force not to download the file. Instead it must get plugin to display. Is there any alternative to `<embed>`?

Comment: I strongly advise against forcing the user to behave a certain way. There are probably reasons why the user does not have such a plugin installed. For example I myself would not go and install the proprietary Adobe Reader with all its bugs but simply leave your page instead if I'd see such a strategy.

Comment: @arkascha: yeah. even i don't want the user to be forced to download the plugin. But if the browser not able to show the file then it must not start downloading the file. That thing I'm asking for

Comment: The fact that the browser does not render the document _inline_ does not mean it cannot be displayed! Those are two separate things. There are good reasons to display a pdf document in a standalone browser. I do agree that you have a problem if a browser without pdf renderer plugin does not offer to open the pdf, but only to download the pdf document into a file. But then the solution is not to prevent the download, but to fix the headers so that the browsers offers to or directly opens the document. That is a question of the http headers you send. Show the headers you send!

Comment: @arkascha: yeah.. there's a reason. coz my client has asked me to

Comment: Sorry, can't follow there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the https://docs.google.com/viewer to accomplish this.

All you do is enter the link and it wil generate a link
Use an iframe with that link to get it embedded